# Semi-transparent div that turns opaque when cursor is over them

Tags: transparency

I have a wordpress site and i would like to make a welcome page with a full screen background image and 2 small, responsive and centered frames (div?) with semi-transparency background but opaque text. 
When the cursor is over one of the div, i want to make it fully opaque just like this website :  http://www.newzealand.com/

As a beginner can you help me please as for now i used png that include text but of course my text turn semitransparent too...
here's my website : http://vincentfournet.fr/

thanks a lot

Comment: You should put your code in the question or make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background style of your div.rgba() gives you the transparency. And use :hover pseudo-element. (IE6 does not support :hover on div. You can use javascript to achieve compatibility, if you do need to cater for those old-browser users)

```
<div class='container'>
  <div id='div1'> TEXT HERE </div>
  <div id='div2'> NORE TEXT </div> 
</div>
//css, other styles ommited
#div1:hover, #div2:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);} /*95% opaque*/
.container {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}
```

I think it will do the trick. here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/2Rpps/